# Java Gui communication with serial port

Tags: java, swing, serial-port, runnable

I have Class, that receive and send information from serial port:

```
public class Terminal implements Runnable
{
    static LinkedList<String> receiver = new LinkedList<String>();
    public Terminal()
    {
        //...
    }
    public String getReceivedMessage()
    {
        String data = receivedMessfges.removeFirst();
        return data;
    }
    // Other function that perform connection to COM port
    // ...
}
```

Also I have Swing based gui class:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame
{
// Functions that display information, received from COM port
}
```

What is the right method of delivering information from `Terminal` to `Gui` using third class:

```
public class Monitor
{
    static Gui gui;
    static terminal terminal;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        monitor = new Monitor();
    }
    public Monitor()
    {
        gui = new Gui();
        terminal = new Terminal();
    }
    // Functions, that get information COM port
    // using getReceivedMessage() function
    // and display it on Gui
}
```

Thanks)

Comment: I get solution using Runnable interface for `Monitor` class. But there is I need to get sleep and it can be the cause of losted data. Is there any crafty method of sending data from `Terminal` to `Gui` without "introducing" them with each other ( that there are no dependencies between classes `Terminal` and `Gui` )

Comment: Is `receivedMessfges.removeFirst();` a blocking function?

Comment: I think yes. It is function implemented in Java standart collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Monitor` class to communicate between `Gui` and `Terminal`.

If `receivedMessfges.removeFirst();` doesn't return until it has received a complete message that should be displayed in the gui, you could just do this:

```
Thread messageChecker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
            String message = terminal.getReceivedMessage();
            // Prepare message for gui display
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    gui.methodToDisplayTheReceivedMessage(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

somewhere inside the `Monitor` class.

The code does the following:

- create a new Runnable (anonymous class)

  - With a `run()` method in which we

    - check if the thread has been interrupted
    - if it has, stop
    - if it hasn't, wait until we have a new message from the and send it to the gui.
- create a new Thread set to execute the `run()` method of our new Runnable
- start this Thread.
- Assign a reference to the Thread to the variable `messageChecker`.

To stop the Thread, simply call `messageChecker.interrupt();`.

If, on the other hand, `terminal.getReceivedMessage();` return only partial messages, i.e. what has been received up until we call it, I think the best approach would be to use the Observer pattern.

- make the terminal class implement the interface [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)
- make the Monitor class implement the interface [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)

Then, you need to write code to notify the observers of a complete message as soon as the terminal class has one. I would suggest to have a Thread internal to the Terminal class checking periodically for new data. As soon as it has a complete message, it should call `notifyObservers(message)` (with `message` obviously being a variable of type `String` containing the complete message).

In the Monitor class, you have to have an `update(Observable o, Object arg)` method to satisfy the `Observer` interface:

```
// In the Monitor class
void update(Observable terminal, Object message) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        gui.methodToDisplayTheReceivedMessage((String)message); // This cast is safe, since we only ever call notifyObservers() with a string argument.
    }
}
```

Last but not least, you need to call `terminal.addObserver(this);` from the Monitor class (from the constructor, probably), otherwise `notifyObservers()` will notify all your 0 observers and nothing happens.

Googling for the "java observer pattern" yields lots of useful resources and examples, in case you want to know more about it.

Comment: Isn't it time to move on to Java 8? ;)

Comment: @user1803551 Good point! My computer is so old it doesn't even support Java 7, so I didn't follow the recent Java updates. 

Comment: Then be careful with your answers. JDK6 is quite old now and many things changed. You should use the most recent API and conventions.

Comment: I miss there invokeLater as notifier for EDT

Comment: @mKorbel Didn't think of that. But wouldn't it be more appropriate to have that inside `gui.methodToDisplayReceivesMessage();`

Comment: @11684 ... point of view, be sure that the EDT must be described in your answer, otherwise its degraded your good answer here (probably EDT is OPs major issue), because AWT/Swing doesn't react to signal from Worker Thread (without programatically to notify the EDT), good point is that somewhere inside must be some method (from AWT/Swing APIs) wrapped into invokeLater, but OP would need to know about

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your comment. Do the first three dots mean your last comment is a continuation of your previous comment? In that case, I'm not sure what the EDT _point of view_ is. In case the dots mean something else, I don't understand what the dots mean, nor what point of view you mean. @mKorbel

Comment: Will add the invokeLater part, though.

Comment: Pattern Observer is exactly what I need! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @11684 ... my plus one :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use an external interface, like writing your data into a file and read from there....

Comment: i don't see a problem in 'introducing each other' - if you use interfaces you can simply exchange your gui or your terminal

Comment: This seems like a lot of overhead for something that could be solved easily using the Observer pattern or just simple blocking.

Comment: @11684 i do know that - but that the question clearly points out that there shall be NO coupling between each other...

Comment: I can't find where the question forbids coupling. As I read it, the OP has to use the Monitor class to communicate between those, which IMHO (sincere H) implies coupling between Monitor and Terminal and between Monitor and Gui is allowed.

Comment: @Martin Frank I also thought about the implementation of the interface "Terminal" after it took to implement the connection to the CAN bus. But the application of the pattern "Observer" seemed more logical in an environment where messages from the terminal may come at any time. It seems every problem has a lot of ways to solve. Thanks for idea)

Comment: @user3583807 as mentioned above i myself would use a listener as well (observer pattern)... but sometimes there are other needs to be fulfilled... i just showed an option for doing it in another way... (i really wouldn't do it with files but only if i have to - maybe if my boss tells me to do so...)